# Issue with multiplication 0.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have values and when I diveded with 0.1 and multiply with 0.1 I don't have the value that I expected.

Exemple :

```
X=963.9
```

I have this formula :

```
Y=int(X/0.1)*0.1
```

I expected Y=963.9 but I have 963.9000000000001
I would like to have the same number.

With some other number like

```
X=963.8
```

result = 963.7 and I expected =963.8

I don't understand why !!
Help